# How to remove cookies on Finatra?

Tags: scala, finagle, finatra

How do I remove a cookie after processing the request and building the response?

I have tried the following code, but it does not seem to work:

```
get("/login") { request =>
  val message = request.cookies.get("flash-message").map(_.value)
  request.removeCookie("flash-message")
  render.view(LoginView(message)).toFuture
}
```

I could not find any methods on `ResponseBuilder` that would remove a cookie, either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out, the way to do it, is the usual "JavaScript" way. Just create an expired cookie and send back, like this:

```
import com.twitter.finagle.http.Cookie
import com.twitter.util.Duration
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit

get("/login") { request =>
  val message = request.cookies.get("flash-message").map(_.value)
  val c = Cookie("flash-message", "")
  c.maxAge = Duration(-10, TimeUnit.DAYS)
  render.view(LoginView(message)).cookie(c).toFuture
}
```

Of course 10 days is just an arbitrary "duration" in the past.